# Is there a formula to multiply two column only if both of them not null?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, sumifs

beginner here.

So I have to find a value with calculation like this: Sum of Column C * Sum of Column B / Sum of Column B. But the problem is both of Column B and C have to be not null. I use excel 2007 fyi.

I'm trying SUMIF but confused in how to corporate it. I used SUMPRODUCT but it calculate every cell, basically I want it to calculate only if there is a pair of data. For now I'm doing it manually =((B3`*`C3)+(B4`*`C4)+(B6`*`C6)+(B11`*`C11))/(B3+B4+B6+B11). But is there a formula I can use because there are so many rows and doing it manually will waste so much time. Sorry if it's a little bit confusing but I attached the image of data dummy that I use. This calculation and requirement is only for Cell C14. Thank you in advance

***Data dummy:***

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try below for ***Excel-2007***.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B3:B13*C3:C13*(B3:B13<>"")*(C3:C13<>""))/SUMPRODUCT(B3:B13*(B3:B13<>"")*(C3:C13<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It didn't work at first and I was so confused but then I realized some of my cells have '0' value haha. I'll try it to my actual data

Comment: In that case you can try number comparing like `=SUMPRODUCT(B3:B13*C3:C13*(B3:B13>0)*(C3:C13>0))/SUMPRODUCT(B3:B13*(B3:B13>0)*(C3:C13>0))
`